# submenu under my menu with z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have this menu : http://jsfiddle.net/gywcv/

I tried to put the "Test" submenu under the pink bar, but i didn't find the solution.

I tested with `position:relative`, `position:absolute` etc:

```
header .container-fluid nav ul li div.submenu {
    height: auto;
    min-height:45px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: rgb( 205, 205, 205 );
    border-style: solid;
    background-color: rgb( 255, 255, 255 );
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgb( 0, 0, 0 );
    margin-top: 12px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: Try assigning the same `position` to the `.logo` div. I believe z-index requires both elements to have a position.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by *Test submenu under the pink bar*, it is already under the menu-bar, no?

Comment: You're missing a closing `nav` tag, btw.

Comment: Ok for the </nav>.
Test submenu under the pink bar : submenu div under the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/bradleytrager/k8CfZ/

You have to make your "Test" submenu's position relative and then set a value for top:

```
header .container-fluid nav ul li div.submenu{
    /*display:none;*/
    height: auto;
    min-height:45px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: rgb( 205, 205, 205 );
    border-style: solid;
    background-color: rgb( 255, 255, 255 );
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgb( 0, 0, 0 );
    margin-top: 12px;
    color:#000000;
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the submenu div is not really under the header (pink bar)

Comment: If you would like it lower down then you can increase the value of top:10px;

Answer (score 0):

There's not really any need to use z-index in your menu. Take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/Diddledot/n7Azr/1/

```
nav ul {
    top: 50px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
nav ul li {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80px;
    margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    float: left;
}
nav li li {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}
nav li:hover li {
    display: block;
}
```